# Comparing nonlinear regression coefficients from independent datasets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonlinear-regression, regression-coefficients

I performed enzyme kinetics experiments on a three independent preparations of an enzyme and produced the following three datasets which I separately fit to the Michaelis-Menten equation:

$$
V= \frac{V_{max} \times S}{K_m + S}
$$

I used R / nlme's nlsList function to do the fitting:

```
fit=nlsList(V~Vm*S/(Km+S)|prep,data=na.omit(kinetics),start=c(Vm=3.5,Km=50))
```

and I get some coefficient values that make sense and some reasonable predicted curves:

[image: V versus S plot of 3 enzymes]

how can I test for differences between the coefficients ($V_{max}$ and $K_m$) between the preparations? I think I can perform a t-test using the coefficient estimates and standard errors but I am not sure how.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has a duplicate somewhere. Ah, found it. Not quite an *exact* duplicate, but the approach [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44246/nls-curve-fitting-of-nested-shared-parameters/44249#44249) should work

Comment: Ok, If I do that approach I can combine all my data into a single fit. I still don't know how to determine whether the coefficients are different.

Comment: There's a couple of ways that should work. Oh, actually, rather than try to type it all in a comment, see for example, pages 16-17 [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/wbl/nlreg). There are other tests, but hopefully that will assist you enough.

Comment: I am not sure what is on those pages that is relevant to what I'm trying to assess, but on page 13 and 14 there is an example using the puromycin dataset that is helpful. I can add one or two explicit difference variables to the model 

`V~(Vm+deltaVm1.2*indicator2+deltaVm1.3*indicator3+S)*S/(Km+deltaKm1.2*indicator2+deltaKm1.3*indicator3S)`

and use dummy coding to determine the difference that going from prep 1 to prep 2 and prep 1 to prep 3 produces. But I'm still missing the comparison from prep 2 to prep 3.

Comment: You can either (i) fit two models, one where prep2 and prep3 have the same dummies, and one where they have different dummies and compare them using an F test via the information I indicated, or (ii) reparameterize so that you have a single dummy representing the contrast (that difference in the two preparations) and test it via a t-test or F-test. (Well there are other ways but those should work okay). Failing that, if you post some data I could see if I could explain how to do it using your data as an example.

Comment: This answers the question! Don't think the site will let me accept a comment as answer though.

Comment: Since the previous answer I first pointed to didn't solve it, I will expand a little on the above and post it as an answer.

Comment: On second thoughts, Yashka, I hadn't picked up before that you were actually doing a mixed model. I'm not sure that I understand enough about nonlinear mixed modelling to write a reasonably intelligent answer. So I'll leave it alone now that I get that. Hopefully someone with more experience with nlme's will respond.

Answer (score 2):

The equation you are using is the Michaelis-Menten equation.  In 1934 Lineweaver and Burk wrote a linear transform for this equation by taking the reciprocal of both sides or

1/v = 1/Vmax +Km/V*S

There are other linear transforms for the Michaelis Menten equation, See "Enzyme Kinetics" by Segel.  Now it is usually preferable to do a linear transform when doing an analysis of of this sort.  The R code is easier and you can simply use an analysis of variance to see if the slopes of your lines are equal.  Also, when you do a linear transform, plot the lines.  If they do not appear straight, then the system you are modeling is not strictly Michaelis-Menten.  You have the wrong model.

Comment: The L-B model does have some drawbacks (transforms near zero have increased error, etc) and I thought with modern computers there was no reason to do an inverse transform to linear, with all of the error that incorporates, when I could just fit a nonlinear model.

In the end I did use the L-B equation and a linear model, though, because it was easier, as you said.