# Comparing fitted parameters of power-law distributions

Tags: repeated-measures, maximum-likelihood, multiple-comparisons, power-law

I estimated using maximum likelihood the parameters of power law distributions, I would like to compare the exponents fitted to data from different regions and also to data from the same region but different years (repeated measures). I have the fitted parameters and the sd estimated by bootstrapping, so I could use multiple t-tests and paired t-test, but I think there should be a better approach. I couldn't figure out how to use the approach given here  [nls curve fitting of nested/shared parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44246/nls-curve-fitting-of-nested-shared-parameters/44249#44249) -- besides the dataset is so huge that fitting a common model would be very difficult.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I finally took was to use generalized least squares, I added weights based on the bootstraped confidence intervals obtained from each fitted exponent (par1) and autoregressive correlation structure for the years. The weights are calculated as UpperCI - LowerCI. Using R, model was as follows:

```
# Sample data
#
ss="id   region  year    par1   weight
1     OC2  2001 1.97534 0.170793
2     OC2  2002 1.99776 0.167792
3     OC2  2003 1.99351 0.171668
4     OC2  2004 1.94659 0.153940
5     OC2  2005 1.99747 0.229509
6     OC2  2006 1.89831 0.150092
7     OC2  2008 1.91301 0.148176
8     OC2  2010 1.86258 0.155380
9     OC2  2011 1.90425 0.180731
10    OC2  2012 1.93237 0.170438
11    OC3  2001 1.93962 0.162383
12    OC3  2004 1.90196 0.123228
13    OC3  2005 1.88369 0.165451
14    OC3  2006 1.88273 0.141107
15    OC3  2007 1.84606 0.137544
16    OC3  2009 1.84473 0.127254
17    OC3  2011 1.92112 0.133714
18    OC3  2012 1.83506 0.190731
19    OC3  2013 1.88946 0.128481
20    OC3  2014 1.95746 0.128612"

ff <-read.delim(text=ss,sep = "")

m1.gls <-gls(par1 ~ region*year,data=ff,weights = varFixed(~weight), correlation = corAR1(form=~year| region))

anova(m1.gls)
summary(m1.gls)
```